# MVC and ViewController structure for iPhone "viewer" app

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, templates, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a series of "book-like" apps and am trying to setup a template of sorts to be used across the series. I've decided against the UINavigationController approach, as it would seem to be too memory-intensive to have an accumulating stack of all pages and their assets.

I'm thinking of a simple RootViewController that manages the loading/destroying of **Previous, Current and Next** views. Does anyone know of a good template or example to start from for this basic skeleton? Preferably one with clear MVC separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [good example app "PageControl"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple which demonstrates this approach with the UIScrollView. I've used that code successfully in a project. I think it should be easy to adapt that way of handling the three views for a custom controller.

Answer (score 0):

**My Approach:**

You could use the three controller (`previousPageController`,`currentPageController`,`NextPageController`) with `UINavigationController` rather then (As you said) having an accumulating stack of all pages and their assets,

If you have single controller like `RootViewController` for showing pages through  three  different views,Although you could go with this approach but you will end up having thousand like of code (could be :)) and that will require more maintenance, So It's better to have three different files responsible for pages rather then One.....

Thanks